# Can .Net version of ArcGIS Server expose Oracle spatial data without ArcSDE, or is this limited to Java version?

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-10.2, oracle-spatial

I'm planning a new deployment of ArcGIS Server and I want to avoid using ArcSDE if possible. My vendor requires that we store our spatial data in Oracle and we prefer to use Microsoft server technologies whenever possible.

Our ideal environment is to host ArcGIS Server on Windows Server and expose the REST services over IIS.

Can the .Net version of ArcGIS Server expose Oracle spatial data without ArcSDE or is this limited to the Java version?

Comment: By Oracle spatial data, I mean the SDO_Geometry data type that Oracle Locator provides.

Comment: "Without ArcSDE" is a self-limiting requirement, since the Direct Connect protocol used to connect to the database *is* ArcSDE (in both Java and .Net implementations). In fact, it is *because* the ArcSDE communication protocol could be expanded to support native tables (Query Layers) that native (or ST_GEOMETRY) tables *can* be exposed without the enterprise geodatabase metadata archive.